# Restrict attribute to property type

Tags: c#, reflection, types, properties, attributes

Using the `AttributeUsage` attribute, I can restrict the valid targets for an attribute to certain entity types (class, property, etc.). However, how can restrict it further so that it can only be applied to properties of a certain type?

For example:

```
[MyAttribute] // Valid
public Foo Item { get; set; }

[MyAttribute] // Compilation error: "Attribute 'MyAttribute' is only valid on classes derived from Foo"
public int Value { get; set; }
```

I'm pretty sure this should be feasible, because the `AttributeUsage` attribute itself has this restriction if we try to apply it to a class that isn't derived from `Attribute` :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)] // Attribute 'AttributeUsage' is only valid on classes derived from System.Attribute
public class Bar { }
```

Comment: There is no mechanism to do this out of the box. The restriction of the `AttributUsageAttribute` is enforced by the compiler, but there is no way to extend the requirements.

Comment: You might be able to use a [Roslyn analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019) to enforce this restriction, though I think users of your attribute can bypass it if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until further notice, accepted answer is, as @thehennyy pointed out, and I feared, that it isn't applicable to custom attributes and is rather enforced by the compiler for the AttributeUsage attribute.